# Unread SMS tray notification stays after marking SMS as read

Tags: android, sms

I've written an application that handles incoming SMS. Everything works great and also marking the processed SMS works. The only thing that doesn't seem to care is the tray notification. It still sits there in the tray and claims there is an unread message (just like the standard SMS app with its little green "1" does). I checked that the message actually is marked as read using the method used in the smspopup sample application, which seems to have the same problem. If I just say "close" on the received message, the tray icon is not updated. Do I miss something here? Do I have to send something like a notification to the tray that it should check again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about notification bar then application which sent that notification to android system should cancel it by calling notificationmanagers cancel(int id) method.
By making SMS read do not clears this notifications, when you go to that sms application(stock sms app may be) then that will call cancel notification method to clear notification bar.
SMS POPUP like apps can not clear notification bar of other stock SMS app.

Comment: Thanks for your response....
but i was asking that default sms application is indicating on its logo that 1 message is unread how will i tell the default application and other applications on the devices that the sms state is changed please update your indications